# OSGI export package

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

I need to import a package A for my projects. However, the import can't be resolved. So I looked into the export package file from the package I need.

I am using Equinox, spring, and maven.  All following code is inside the pom.xml file.

```
// E.D.C.B.A

!E.D.C.B.F*
!E.D.C.B.G*
!E.D.C.B.Z*
E.D.C.B*,
!*
```

This question could be narrowed down to two simple questions.

1. Does `E.D.C.B*` include `E.D.C.B`?
2. what does `!*` mean? Does it mean exports no packages or export no package expect those are specified?

For my understanding, I think the code above means export no package expect those are specified. All packages in `E.D.C.B*` (like `E.D.C.B` and `E.D.C.Bbdfd`) are allowed except those in `E.D.C.B.F*`, `E.D.C.B.G*` and `E.D.C.B.G*`.

Comment: You need to specify your development environment .... is this bnd? Gradle/Maven/Bndtools??

Comment: @PeterKriens Thanks for correcting.

Comment: which maven plugin are you using? Maybe showing the actual pom would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your questions:

I am assuming you are talking about the `Export-Package` instruction from the Apache Felix [`maven-bundle-plugin`](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html). If this is not correct, please be more specific.

1. Yes, `E.D.C.B*` will export package `E.D.C.B` and sub-packages.
2. `!*` usually is not needed if you're already specifying the packages that you intend to export before, but generally means: `not (any package)`

Your final understanding is correct in this case.

Also note that instructions are processed in-order, so that exclusions or inclusions specified first take precedence over following declarations, which is why `!*` does not make any sense, actually.

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally found all that I need inside Apache Felix docs.